# Unable to "Safely Remove" flash drive after calling Process.Start and terminating

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have a following application I want to run from a flash drive, say *F:\App.exe*:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\AnotherApp.exe");
}
```

However, after *App.exe* terminates, it is impossible to "Safely Remove" drive F: until *AnotherApp.exe* terminates as well. When viewing the process tree using *Sysinternals Process Monitor*, process *AnotherApp.exe* is still a child of *App.exe* (which is terminated).

Is there a way to start a process from an application on a flash drive, that would not block its safe removal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.Start` always spawns a process as child of the lauching application.

Even if you terminate the parent, the child will still be an orphan of that one, and I think it still holds the parent handles.

**EDIT:**

OK, I got it.
The problem is that the child process is started with `F:\` as its current directory.
You can create process using `CreatePocess()` through [`P/Invoke`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createprocess), and the set a different starting directory (I've tested it and it works).

Example here:

http://pastebin.com/QsMqejS5

Comment: +1. Note: By default, Process uses ShellExecuteEx. Set the parameter `UseShellExecute` to false of the ProcessStartInfo parameter, and internally it'll use `CreateProcess`. That will remove the need to use P/Invoke.

Comment: @Abel: I have tested that approach, but the starting dir doesn't change, so you can't detach the USB...

Comment: Pity, it would've been a nice (simpler) solution.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose there isn't a way of doing it without using unsafe code?

Comment: @Bohdan: Unfortunately no :( ...BTW, I suggest you to wrap this code (perahps making it more generic) in another assembly, so you won't need to compile your current project with the unsafe option ;)

Comment: @digEmAll: Actually changing the type of `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.lpSecurityDescriptor` from `unsafe byte*` to `int` makes the code safe, but of course it's not a nice way of achieving it...

Comment: The problem is not unsafe code, but actually that we need to switch to unmanaged code for this thing :(